# WebAPI DataMember Name not used when de/serializing via application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

Already spent couple of hours trying to resolve issue with ignored `Name` property on `DataMemberAttribute` when handling HTTP POST form request (`Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`).

I'm having `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi 5.2.3` application running on .NET 4.5, hosted by IIS.

I have this model (demo):

```
// library
public interface IPayload
{
    string DataId { get; set; }
    int RelationId { get; set; }
}

// web app project
[DataContract]
public class MyPayload : IPayload
{
    [Required]
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public string DataId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataMember(Name = "rel")]
    public int RelationId { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("~/api/stuff")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> DoMagic(MyPayload payload)
{
    // ... breakpoint
}
```

(Note I'm really using model type and not just interface in my controller)

---

When I send data like this:

```
curl -X POST --data '{"id":"foo","rel":1}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Content-Length: 20" http://localhost/api/stuff
```

I get my model deserialized correctly.

---

However, when I do:

```
curl --data "id=foo" --data "rel=1" http://localhost/api/stuff
```

... I'm getting empty model - custom name is ignored, all properties have default value.

Finally, when I do request like this:

```
curl --data "DataId=foo" --data "RelationId=1" http://localhost/api/stuff
```

... model is serialized correctly.

---

So I'm wondering, what am I doing wrong. I spent quite a lot of reading, most of cases I found were about missing `DataContractAttribute` which is present in my case.

Attribute `FromBody` in front of controller parameter is not changing anything as well.

In my application, these formatters are registered:

- `System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter`
- `System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter`
- `System.Net.Http.Formatting.FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter`
- `System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.JQueryMvcFormUrlEncodedFormatter`

Only last two contain `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in `SupportedMediaTypes`.

Comment: Did you already try [FromUri] attribute?

Comment: To be honest, I haven't as content is really in body - and if I try to use it, I'm actually getting `null`

I also tried `ModelBinder` (empty, as I haven't implemented any custom binder) and it didn't help me much as well. Also, I wouldn't go this way - for JSON it works, so why should I implement binder here?

Comment: But you state "when handling HTTP POST form request (`Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`)"?

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I meant simply when my action handler `DoMagic` is invoked due to POST request. I'm expecting data in request body (as would anyone expect from POST, right? :)) -- so basically, I'm sending POST payload. If I send JSON with appropriate `Content-Type` header, it works. It does not work when I submit form (`method="post"`).

Comment: What does your `RequestContext.RouteData` and `Request.Content` look like? I'm not familiar with curl but what I see [here](http://blog.scottlowe.org/2014/02/19/using-curl-to-interact-with-a-restful-api/) is somewhat different than your posts.

Comment: Not really sure where are you heading: RouteData points to correct route, there is no Value in `HttpRouteValueDictionary` (which is correct, there's no query string parameter in my case); `Request.Content` has correct headers set `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` but when I read it's content via `Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` I'm getting empty string.

Answer (score 11):

After time spent on debugging, I have to answer myself.

`System.Net.Http.Formatting.FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter` is not used as my model is not derived from `FormDataCollection` nor is JS token type. So formatter `System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.JQueryMvcFormUrlEncodedFormatter` is in use.

Binders used within `CompositeModelBinder` are:

- `TypeMatchModelBinder` (skipped)
- `MutableObjectModelBinder` (used)

I haven't found any trace of code, which would take in consideration `Name` attribute of `DataMemberAttribute` - so I have to implement own `IModelBinder` for my type, which will take care of customization.

Just note: when serializing object, everything works as expected - issue described above is related only to deserializing from request body.

Sources

- [System.Net.Http.Formatting.Formatting](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/latest#src/System.Net.Http.Formatting/Formatting/)
- [System.Web.Http.ModelBinding](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/latest#src/System.Web.Http/ModelBinding/)

I hope I haven't missed anything. If so, please correct me.